# About graph symmetric with respect to the origin.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, symmetry

[image]

Why it is called a reflection about the y-axis followed by a reflection about the x-axis?

Comment: Because it is odd? Reflect about $y$-axis, then $(x,y)$ becomes $(-x,y)$ and then reflect about $x$-axis $(-x,y)$ becomes $(-x,-y)$

Comment: @samjoe can i say reflection about the x-axis followed by a reflection about the y-axis.

Comment: Yes that's about the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way, which is intuitive. The description is equivalent to say that you fold the plane with respect to the vertical axis and then fold the "half plane" with respect to the horizontal axis; then the north-east graph coincides with the south-west graph.